# toggling css display values on click

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to `.toggle` the value of the css display attribute back and forth (on element parent) every click. ive managed to toggle the show dont show on the nested ul i want. but im not managing to switch from `inline-block`, to `inline` on the parent. How would i do this.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="reveal">
        Test<br />
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').css('display', 'inline');
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Please always provide fiddles so that the people who help you don't have to.

Comment: Why would you want this behaviour? Could it be an XY problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="disInlineBlock">
  <li class="reveal">Test<br />
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.disInlineBlock{display:inline-block;}
.disInline{display:inline;}
```

**Script**

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').toggleClass('disInline');
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: toggling a class when it comes to styling should always be the preferred method imho +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
$('.reveal').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent('ul');
    if (parent.css('display') === 'inline') {
        parent.css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
        parent.css('display', 'inline');
    }
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This does what i wanted to do. Educationally, I'm still interested in knowing how to achieve the same with .toggle, if possible.